# Moving trail of Particles forming rings when the emitter is constrained to "Follow Path"

Tags: animation, particles, bezier-curves, path

EDIT:
The answers found in this previously asked question didn't help: [Particles are clumping on each frame](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17704/particles-are-clumping-on-each-frame)

I'm trying to use particles, which are moving along a path,by following an animated emitter. Basically it's supposed to look like sparks coming out of a firework's propeler.

PROBLEM
My particles are forming rings/clusters while moving. They used to look random (as it should be) but it starts to form clusters when you constrain the emitter to "Follow Path".

Only way to not get clustering is by manually building the animation (not an option on the long run)

[image: Rings in orange]